# how to check if the user interact with any widgets and execute a function in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm not a beginner but I don't know
how to check if the user interacts with any widgets and execute a function in Tkinter

what I expected is like

```
root.bind("<interact>", do_something())
```

edit :

I got the answer

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

def printzero(event):
    print(0)

btn1 = Button(text="                    e                        ")
btn1.pack()
btn1 = Button(text="                    e                        ")
btn1.pack()
btn1 = Button(text="                    e                        ")
btn1.pack()

txt1 = Text()
txt1.pack()

root.bind("<Button-1>", printzero)
root.bind("<Button-2>", printzero)
root.bind("<Button-3>", printzero)
root.bind("<Key>", printzero)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a function to an event for a widget, you're not actually binding to the widget. Instead, you are binding to a tag (or *binding tag*). When a widget receives an event, it looks at every binding tag for the widget to see if they are bound to a function.

By default, every widget gets itself as a binding tag, and it also gets the special tag "all". You can bind to this tag to have the event fire no matter which widget gets the event.

For example, assuming you have a widget in the variable `root`, and a function called `notify`, the following will cause the function to be called whenever you click on any widget, or press any key, in the whole GUI:

```
root.bind_all("<Any-ButtonPress>", notify)
root.bind_all("<Any-KeyPress>", notify)
```

Here's a working example that updates a label every time you click a mouse button or press a key:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
output_label = tk.Label(root, width=40)
entry = tk.Entry(root)
text = tk.Text(root, width=40, height=4, yscrollcommand=lambda *args: scrollbar.set(*args))
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=text.yview)
button = tk.Button(root, text="A button")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, background="bisque", width=200, height=200)

output_label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button.pack(side="bottom")
canvas.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

counter = 0
def notify(event):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    output_label.configure(text=f"count: {counter} widget: {event.widget}")

root.bind_all("<Any-ButtonPress>", notify)
root.bind_all("<Any-KeyPress>", notify)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: i know it and i tried it it good

Answer (score -1):

So The main way I would recommend is to call a function and have that function notify you or carry out whatever desired information you have. In as simple of code as possible I have included.

```
from tkinter import *

def buttonClicked():
  print("button was clicked")
top = Tk()
send = Button(top, text='Send', command=buttonClicked)
send.pack(side=LEFT)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: it worked only for buttons

Comment: Look up the trace() in Tkinter. that should help

Comment: trace is of no use for detecting interaction with widgets. For example, trace is useless for calling a function when you click on a canvas or scroll a scrollbar.